# Django subquery/prefech_related

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

For example, I have models:

```
class Location(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...

class ControlPoint(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Локация')
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    route = models.ForeignKey('Route', related_name='control_points', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Route(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    @property
    def get_departure(self):
        return self.control_points.get(order=0)

    @property
    def get_arrival(self):
        return self.control_points.order_by('-order')[0]

    def clear_control_points(self):
        self.control_points.all().delete()


class Trip(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    route = models.OneToOneField(Route, related_name='trips', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='trips', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

**RESOLVE**

Based on cengineer's answer below (I'm very grateful to him):

```
Trip.objects.filter(route_id__in=Subquery(ControlPoint.objects.filter(location_id=<location_id>).values('route_id')))
```

If you know how to solve this problem differently, I will be glad to see your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can solve this problem with Subquery. In your case it should be like this

```
Trip.objects.filter(route_id__in=Subquery(ControlPoint.objects.filter(location_id=<your_location_id>).values('id')))
```

So I have used `route_id` because when you have a `ForeignKey` in your model, say `x` it is stored as `x_id` and I think this is more readable but you can use route of course if you want.

Comment: Thank you) Slight amendment:    
```Trip.objects.filter(route_id__in=Subquery(ControlPoint.objects.filter(location_id=<your_location_id>).values('route_id')))```